# Cursor script runs but not updating value

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, cursor

I have a script I wrote to use an update cursor to change any records in a feature class that has a field set to 'N' to 'Y'(coded domain values). I have ensured that the database connection file is in the same directory folder as the script. The script runs with no errors but the values do not update in the database. This is an enterprise database in Oracle with ArcFM-ified features. Any suggestions?

```
import arcpy
import os
import sys

arcpy.env.workspace = workspace = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'connectionFile.sde')
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


fc = "FC_Name"
field = "Field_Name"
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)
edit.startEditing(False, True)
edit.startOperation()
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field) as cursor:
    try:
        for row in cursor:
            if row == "N":
                row.setValue(field, 'Y')
                ##row = "Y" #This way also did not work
                cursor.updateRow(row)
    except Exception:
        e = sys.exc_info()[1]
        print(e.args[0])
     
edit.stopOperation()
edit.stopEditing(save_changes=True)
```

Comment: You have a mixture of DA and deprecated cursor syntaxes (setValue() is not defined on an array).  For this reason, it is always best to disable all `try` blocks in the course of documenting your code for a Question.

Comment: If you `print(str(row))` and `print(str(row == "N"))` inside the loop (above the `if`) you'll see the error here -- `['N']' != 'N'`. Your `updateRow` line should be `cursor.updateRow(['Y'])`

Comment: `if row == "N":` should be `if row[0] == "N":`, row is a tuple, like this: `("N",)` so it will never be "N", you need to fetch the string in it using first index

Comment: Ok I have changed my code a couple different ways but still getting an 'error return without exception set' result. This is the updated version.
`for row in cursor:
            if row[0] == 'N':
                cursor.updateRow(['Y'])`

Comment: Try row[0] = "Y" and cursor.updateRow(row) after your if statement.

Comment: I have also tried this.. Still getting an error at cursor.updateRow(row): "SystemError: error return without exception set" Seems like it may have something to do with our enterprise system? I have checked for exclusive locks on the feature and only shared locks exist..